# Use array for a tree structure coming from ajax response

Tags: ajax, arrays

I've two xml files, one `category` & second `products`. I need to print a Tree Structure where products within same category should be printed together.
Like this:

```
1. Food
  a. Milk
  b. Cheese
```

I've following code in my file which doesn't work; it doesn't print anything.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "categories.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
    var categories= new Array();;
    $(xml).find('Categories').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).find('CategoryID').text();
        var title = $(this).find('CategoryName').text();
        var desc = $(this).find('Description').text();
        for(i=0;i<=20;i++){
            categories[i]=new Array();
            categories[i][0]= id;
            categories[i][1]= title;
            categories[i][2]= desc;
        }
    });
    }
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "products.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
    var products = new Array();
    $(xml).find('Products').each(function(){
        var proid = $(this).find('ProductID').text();
        var proname = $(this).find('ProductName').text();
        var catid = $(this).find('CategoryID').text();
        var qua=$(this).find('QuantityPerUnit').text();
        var price=$(this).find('UnitPrice').text();
        for(i=0;i<=20;i++){
            products[i]=new Array();
            products[i][0]= proid;
            products[i][1]= proname;
            products[i][2]= catid;
            products[i][3]= qua;
            products[i][4]= price;
        }
    });
    }
});
});
for(k=0;k<20;k++){
    if(categories[k][0]!=""){
    $('#category').append("<div>"+categories[k][1]+"</div>");
    for(l=0;l<20;l++){
        if(categories[k][0]==products[l][2]){
            $('#category').append("<div style='margin-left:10px;'>"+products[l][1]+"</div>");
        }
    }
}
}
</script>
```

What I do is store the array for categories & for products, then loop through all arrays, find products through category id. But it doesn't work, it doesn't print anything. Can anyone help?

**XML Files**

**categories.xml**

```
<CategoriesRoot>
<Categories>
    <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Beverages</CategoryName>
    <Description>Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beer, and ale</Description>
</Categories>
<Categories>
    <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Condiments</CategoryName>
    <Description>
    Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings
    </Description>
</Categories>
<Categories>
    <CategoryID>3</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Confections</CategoryName>
    <Description>Desserts, candies, sweetbreads</Description>
</Categories>
<Categories>
    <CategoryID>4</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Dairy Products</CategoryName>
    <Description>Cheeses</Description>
</Categories>
<Categories>
    <CategoryID>5</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Grains/Cereals</CategoryName>
    <Description>Breads, crackers, pasta, and cereal</Description>
</Categories>
<Categories>
    <CategoryID>6</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Meat/Poultry</CategoryName>
    <Description>Prepared meats</Description>
</Categories>
<Categories>
    <CategoryID>7</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Produce</CategoryName>
    <Description>Dried fruit and bean curd</Description>
</Categories>
<Categories>
    <CategoryID>8</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Seafood</CategoryName>
    <Description>Seaweed and fish</Description>
</Categories>
</CategoriesRoot>
```

**products.xml**

```
<ProductsRoot>
<Products>
    <ProductID>1</ProductID>
        <ProductName>Chai</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
    <QuantityPerUnit>10 boxes x 20 bags</QuantityPerUnit>
    <UnitPrice>18</UnitPrice>
</Products>
<Products>
    <ProductID>2</ProductID>
    <ProductName>Chang</ProductName>
    <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
    <QuantityPerUnit>24 - 12 oz bottles</QuantityPerUnit>
    <UnitPrice>19</UnitPrice>
</Products>
<Products>
    <ProductID>3</ProductID>
    <ProductName>Aniseed Syrup</ProductName>
    <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
    <QuantityPerUnit>12 - 550 ml bottles</QuantityPerUnit>
    <UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>
</Products>
</ProductsRoot>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are scoped within your ajax success calls. Are you not getting errors? And since the ajax calls are asynchronous, you have to make sure both categories and products have returned.

As soon as each `success` function of the ajax requests ends, the `categories` and `products` variables die. They are undefined in the `for` loop where you access them. We need to scope them outside the ajax calls, and then ensure both ajax requests have returned before we run our loop.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var categories = [];
    var products = [];
    var callbacks = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "categories.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('Categories').each(function(){
                var id = $(this).find('CategoryID').text();
                var title = $(this).find('CategoryName').text();
                var desc = $(this).find('Description').text();
                var category = new Array();
                category.push(id);
                category.push(title);
                category.push(desc);
                categories.push(category);
            });
            callback();
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "products.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('Products').each(function(){
                var proid = $(this).find('ProductID').text();
                var proname = $(this).find('ProductName').text();
                var catid = $(this).find('CategoryID').text();
                var qua=$(this).find('QuantityPerUnit').text();
                var price=$(this).find('UnitPrice').text();
                var product = new Array();
                product.push(proid);
                product.push(proname);
                product.push(catid);
                product.push(qua);
                product.push(price);
                products.push(product);
            });
            callback();
        }
    });

    function callback() {
        if(++callbacks < 2) return;
        for(var k=0;k<categories.length;k++){
            if(categories[k][0]!=""){
                $('#category').append("<div>"+categories[k][1]+"</div>");
                for(var l=0;l<products.length;l++){
                    if(categories[k][0]==products[l][2]){
                        $('#category').append("<div style='margin-left:10px;'>"+products[l][1]+"</div>");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I got your point but somehow it takes only last category id & last product id and prints it for as many times as there are category ids in xml file.

Comment: @user3664667 can you supply us with some sample xml?

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with your reference to 'Categories' and 'Products' in your xml. Since it's plural, seems like it might be referencing the outer element encompassing all the individual 'Category' and 'Product' elements. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: I don't think, still I've attached both xml files, you can just have a look at the structure.

Comment: @user3664667 please see updates. The for-loop inside the callbacks was the problem. Changed the for loop to an array that gets pushed to the categories/products array, then just loop through the array size of each at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax are asynchronous and you can not wait javascript to get response. so you will need to perform rest of operation in the response callback function. pl check the below code.

1. Action method should be GET as you not posting anything to xml file.
2. You dont need to iterate for loop in jQuery each method as each itself is a loop
3. use `.length` property of Array instead of hard coded 20 in forloop

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){

   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "categories.xml",
       dataType: "xml",
       success: function(xml) {

           var categories= new Array();

           $(xml).find('Categories').each(function(i){
               var id = $(this).find('CategoryID').text();
               var title = $(this).find('CategoryName').text();
               var desc = $(this).find('Description').text();

               categories[i]=new Array();
               categories[i][0]= id;
               categories[i][1]= title;
               categories[i][2]= desc;
           });

           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "products.xml",
               dataType: "xml",
               success: function(xml) {
                   var products = new Array();
                   $(xml).find('Products').each(function(j){
                       var proid = $(this).find('ProductID').text();
                       var proname = $(this).find('ProductName').text();
                       var catid = $(this).find('CategoryID').text();
                       var qua=$(this).find('QuantityPerUnit').text();
                       var price=$(this).find('UnitPrice').text();

                       products[j]=new Array();
                       products[j][0]= proid;
                       products[j][1]= proname;
                       products[j][2]= catid;
                       products[j][3]= qua;
                       products[j][4]= price;
                   });


                   for(k=0;k<categories.length;k++){
                       if(categories[k][0]!=""){
                           $('#category').append("<div>"+categories[k][1]+"</div>");
                           for(l=0;l<products.length;l++){
                               if(categories[k][0]==products[l][2]){
                                   $('#category').append("<div style='margin-left:10px;'>"+products[l][1]+"</div>");
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }   
               }
           });
       }
   });
   ```

   });

Comment: Problem with this is, it takes last category id & last product and prints it for numerous time, specifically as many times as total category ids.

Comment: @user3664667 if you can show me in http://jsfiddle.net/ that would be better. i can debug it well

Comment: Or can you provide that xml files?

Comment: Yes I can provide xml files, let me try to attach it in this question